# Apache2 mod_rewrite pattern restriction?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have a site that I want to make SEO friendly by using mod_rewrite. I want to make the URLs easy to remember by dropping the .php on the end of them and using mod_rewrite to re-attach them later on. So for example say http://example.com/about would point to http://example.com/about.php. I have the RewriteRule that should work from my experience but for some reason doesn't.

My rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?about$ about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?faq$ faq.php [L]
```

Now these rules don't work like that exactly. it seems that if I rename the files to blah.about.php and blah.faq.php and change the RewriteRule lines to reflect the new filenames it works.

Is this a restriction of mod_rewrite where the Pattern can't be so close to the target file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

First rule redirect the request to phpless page and the next internally to the php file itself.

> Is this a restriction of mod_rewrite where the Pattern can't be so close to the target file?

Its not really a restriction, you just can't redirect the php file to non-php and then back to it as it generates a loop, so what we do is capture the request and redirect from there and then internally redirect to the file.

Unless of course like you have seen they have a different naming.